# how to pagination apply on file reading codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, file, csv

Is it possible to paginate view on **read file**. I have a file of contacts containing 100 000 numbers. When i get it in array how to apply pagination on it?

Controller:

```
<?php 
   $reseller_dnc_phone_arr=array();
    if(@file_exists('resources/'.$this->session->userdata['HP']
      ['memberId'].'/dnc_list.inc')){
       $reseller_dnc_phone_arr=@json_decode(@file_get_contents('resources/'.$this->session->userdata['HP']['memberId'].'/dnc_list.inc'));
    }
    $data['reseller_dnc_phone_arr']=$reseller_dnc_phone_arr;
    $data['view_content']='import-dnc-list';
    $this->load->view('include/content',$data);
?>
```

How can i get the limit number of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have fetched your data in array. You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to limit the records and pass it to views

```
<?php

$data['array_u_got'] = $array_u_got;

//Pagination - Config as you wish.
$this->load->library("pagination");
$config = array();
$config["base_url"]             = base_url() . "controller_path";
$config["total_rows"]           = count($data['array_u_got']);
$config["per_page"]             = 20;
$config['num_links']            = 5;
$config["uri_segment"]          = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers']     = FALSE;

//Pagination Styling
$config['full_tag_open']        = '<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="datatable_paginate"><ul class="pagination">'; 
$config['full_tag_close']       = '</ul></div>'; 
$config['num_tag_open']         = '<li class="paginate_button page-item">'; 
$config['num_tag_close']        = '</li>'; 
$config['cur_tag_open']         = '<li class="paginate_button page-item active"><a class="page-link">'; 
$config['cur_tag_close']        = '</a></li>'; 
$config['prev_tag_open']        = '<li class="paginate_button page-item previous">'; 
$config['prev_tag_close']       = '</li>'; 
$config['next_tag_open']        = '<li class="paginate_button page-item next">'; 
$config['next_tag_close']       = '</li>'; 
$config['attributes']           = array('class' => 'page-link');
$config['first_link']           = 'First'; 
$config['prev_link']            = 'Prev'; 
$config['last_link']            = 'Last'; 
$config['next_link']            = 'Next'; 
$config['first_tag_open']       = '<li class="paginate_button page-item">'; 
$config['first_tag_close']      = '</li>'; 
$config['last_tag_open']        = '<li class="paginate_button page-item">'; 
$config['last_tag_close']       = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

//Results to be Passed to the views
$data['results'] = array_slice($data['array_u_got'], $page, $config["per_page"]);

//Pagination Output
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```